# Run Azure Data factory single activity for backdates

Tags: sql-server, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-data-factory

PROBLEM: I have updated the stored procedure and this stored procedure is run after every 1 hour through Azure-pipeline one activity. This pipeline contains multiple activity but I want to run this specific Activity in pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my knowledge, you can't run single specific activity in one pipeline. Based on the [Azure Data Factory REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-rest-api#create-pipeline-run), only execute pipeline could be found. No such execute activity is supported so far.

It seems the only way is that you clone your activity into another pipeline if your activity doesn't have dependency relationship with other activities.

You could also refer to the similar [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/6d5c2a24-20c3-450b-b866-593cf4f6bdbe/how-to-run-single-activity-in-azure-data-factory-pipeline?forum=AzureDataFactory).

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, I completed above task by running stored procedure by loop iterations hourly. 

I checked on other websites also and found your ans is correct.

Comment: @NitinJain You're welcome, Nitin. If you adopt my answer , you could mark it for others' reference. Thank you.

Comment: I don't know how to mark this correct as I am having only 1 reputation point .

Comment: @NitinJain You could find a gray hook marker beside my answer.Just light it up!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to do it from the Azure portal you can connect the activity you intend to run with the others and then in the connector select the SKIPPED property.